# Error with t-test

Tags: r, bioinformatics, hypothesis-test

I'm having errors with the normal t-test:

```
  data <- read.table("/Users/vdas/Documents/RNA-Seq_Smaples_Udine_08032013/GBM_29052013/UD_RP_25072013/filteredFPKM_matrix.txt",sep="",header=TRUE,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

  PGT <- cbind(data[,2],data[,7],data[,24])
  PDGT <- cbind(data[,6],data[,8])
  pval2 <- NULL
  for(i in 1:length(PGT[,1])){
     pval2 <- c(pval2,t.test(as.numeric(PDGT[i,]),as.numeric(PGT[i,]))$p.value)
     print(i)
  }
```

Error:

```
Error in t.test.default(as.numeric(PDGT[i, ]), as.numeric(PGT[i, ])) : 
  not enough 'x' observations
```

I cannot understand what went wrong with the vector. Can you please tell me? I have not been able to figure it out .

Comment: Show us how your data looks like. Use `str` and `summary`. It would be great if you made your error reproducible with a simple example.

Comment: NAs or not (see comments below), if I get your code right, it seems that you are running t-tests on 'x-vectors' (`t.test` terminology) of length 2 (rows in PDGT) against 'y-vectors of length 3 (rows in PGT). Pretty small samples. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Yes this is true , it is 3 vs 2, but yes I am having a lot values NaN after I run the t.test for some rows , and if I have to remove the low abundance expression value then the matrix size will reduce..

Comment: A small side note: there is no need to split your data frame in two and loop over rows. You may apply your function row-wise on your original data: `pvals <- apply(X = data, MARGIN = 1, function(dd) t.test(x = dd[c(6, 8)], y = dd[c(2, 7, 24)])$p.value)`

Answer (score 5):

Most likely your data have `NA` values. For example: -

```
x<-rep(NA,4)
t.test(x)

Error in t.test.default(x) : not enough 'x' observations
```

Comment: Yes in my data I have NaN values actually these are expression values of genes so some them are very low so they have 0 value for those. Do you think thats the reason for this error? If so in that case I will not be able to perform the t.test as some rows have 3 fields as 0 in one condition and the other fields in second condition is having values. Am I correct?

Comment: It seems to me that the missing values are the reason the `t.test` fails. Best thing to do is skip all rows which have any `NA` values.

Answer (score 1):

From you comment, It seems that error come due to the missing value. You can exclude the missing values by setting `na.rm=TRUE`. Ref:- [Missing value](http://www.statmethods.net/input/missingdata.html) . Before posting R question take a look at [How to make a great R reproducible example?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

To remove `NA` values you do:

```
> a <- sample(c(NA, 1:5), 20, replace = TRUE)
> a
 [1] NA  1  2 NA  1  5  4  4  3  3  2  4 NA  4 NA NA  1  2 NA  5
> b <- na.omit(a)
> b
 [1] 1 2 1 5 4 4 3 3 2 4 4 1 2 5
```